# Asp.net MVC - How can I get user roles without knowing these roles?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, attributes, membership-provider

I'm working on this project that an admin user can create some User's Groups that will be working as the project roles.

So, the admin will create a User Group named "SuperAdmin" and will select in a dropdownlist the users that will be part of this group.

I've worked before in a solution using RoleProvider and using Controller's Attibutes, but in that occasion I created all the groups and set manually in the Controller, like:

```
[Access(Roles = "SuperAdmin")]
public UserController : Controller
{
}
```

In the example above I know that the group is named "SuperAdmin". But, now, in this new project, I don't know what groups an admin user will create.

So how can I get all roles that a user will be allowed to access dynamically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to soft-code the value "SuperAdmin".

I encountered a similar problem, as I wanted to verify that a user had access to a certain resource (call it a document), but that resource's ID was unknown during application development.  I solved it by creating my own table-based security and putting the core logic for it in my model (effectively the business logic layer).  This allows me to security-trim data retrievals from the database, and redirect a user if they are requesting a resource for which they have no access.

If you still want to do it with an attribute, you can create a custom attribute (modeling the one that ASP.NET MVC uses) that looks up the appropriate permissions from the database, and makes a determination.

Or, you can do it right inside the controller method, using something like this:

```
Public ActionResult EditThing(int ID)
{
    ThingRepository repository = new ThingRepository();

    If (!repository.UserHasAccess(int ID))
       Return View("NotAuthorized")
    //
    // Do stuff here
}
```

See the [NerdDinner tutorial](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm) if you need more information on repositories.

More info here: [Document-Based Security in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521189)

Comment: @AndreMiranda - How does the Admin assign RIGHTS to the roles? I.e. what makes the dynamically created SuperAdmin role special? Somewhere you need to store a mapping of roles to permissions - be it editing a page, posting a form, or just accessing a page how are you enabling the admin to define these?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered writing your own attribute that you can decorate your action with?

In that case you could use the attribute to get the access rights for a user, match that against say a page access table and then return the result and either allow or deny access to the page/action.

I think you'll need to have a table which will dictate which pages a role has access to which can be cross referenced to the roles a user is assigned to.

Or you could write your attribute in such a way so that it dictates the roles allowed to see the page.

```
[MyAccessAttribute(Allow="SuperUser", "Admin")]
public ActionResult MyAction()
```

Does this help / make sense?